# How padding is applied in the code?

Tags: c, structure, padding

I read the following code from wikipedia

```
struct MixedData
{
    char Data1;
    short Data2;
    int Data3;
    char Data4;
}md;
printf("%u    %u    %u    %u", &md.Data1, &md.Data2, &md.Data3, &md.Data4);
```

The output is:-

```
268624    268626    268628    268632
```

I am unable to understand how padding is applied after each data member in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/)

> first element is char which is one byte aligned, followed by short
>   int. short int is 2 byte aligned. If the the short int element is
>   immediately allocated after the char element, it will start at an odd
>   address boundary. The compiler will insert a padding byte after the
>   char to ensure short int will have an address multiple of 2 (i.e. 2
>   byte aligned).

This is how your struct looks like:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Data1 |       |     Data2     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|             Data3             |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Data4 |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

So padding from char to `short` is one byte =>

268624 to 268625 is Data1, from 268625 to 268626 padding to `short`.
then 268626  to  268628 `short` no padding needed, all aligned to max type of the struct.

From the same reference

> There is a way to minimize padding. The programmer should declare the
>   structure members in their increasing/decreasing order of size

The way to improve your struct is to place `char Data4;` directly after `char Data1;`
This way no memory will be wasted for padding:

```
struct MixedData
{
    char Data1;
    char Data4;
    short Data2;
    int Data3;

}md;

printf("%p    %p    %p    %p", &md.Data1,&md.Data4, &md.Data2, &md.Data3);

0x602270    0x602271    0x602272    0x602274
```

The basic assumption, that compiler is stick with natural alignment of int on x86

Comment: why only 2 bytes are used before short not 4?

Comment: but if I declare two consecutive `char` as done in your answer, then why padding is not needed?

Comment: In that case your structure is aligned, and no padding needed.What padding did in your case? Added one byte after Data1 to align char to short. Data1 + Data4 = 2 char, 2 char = 2 bytes, short two byte aligned, no additional padding required

Comment: but also `int` requires 4 bytes, so why 2 bytes are not added after `short` in my question?

Comment: because you already added one byte of padding after Data1. Data1 + 1 byte of padding = 2 bytes, after those 2 bytes you have 2 bytes of short 2+2 = 4 => you aligned with your int

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46907/discussion-between-dabo-and-kevin-gomes)

Comment: The padding is unspecified in standard. Different architectures do the padding differently, some allow the programmer to enforce certain padding, some don't. Your answer covers an unknown compiler on an unknown machine with unknown architecture, hence it provides no information at all. The OP did not specify these hence it is impossible to actually answer this question. Or rather the answer is always the same: "the compiler decided so".

Comment: @Dariusz "The compiler decided so" will explain nothing to OP. I will add that my assumption is that my explanation with respect to "natural alignment"

Answer (score 0):

How?

2 bytes for 1 byte char

2 bytes for 2 byte short

4 bytes for 4 byte int

? bytes for 1 byte char

The real question is: **why?**

And the answer to that question is [here, structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing?rq=1) and [here, sizeof != sum (fields)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member?lq=1)

Comment: please tell me how the gap filling is taking place in the code?

Comment: what do you mean by gap filling taking place in the code?